# How do I plot more than one series in the same R scatterplot?

Tags: r, charts

I often visualize one time series against another using scatterplots in Excel, but since recent data are more relavant, I use different highlights for more recent time periods:

[image]

In this case the month, week and today plots are simply different (more recent) slices of the same time series, so basically there are four superimposed plots in this chart. How can I do the same in R? I have gotten so far:

[image]

But i'd like to replicate what I have in excel. How do I add new plots to the same chart in R?

Or perhaps I could even go further and use the col attribute in the R plot to get a continuous increase in the colour up to the today value, thus avoiding these discreet steps? How would I do that?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479822/plotting-4-curves-in-a-single-plot-with-3-y-axes-in-r/5481187#5481187. If using ggplot, you can alter the `alpha` parameter for transparency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a skeleton example of how to go about doing it using `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)

day <- 1:100
dat <- data.frame(
  day=day,
  x = day+(1+rnorm(100, 0, 10)),
  y = 5 + day+(1+rnorm(100, 0, 10)),
  when = cut(day, 5)
)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=when)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

And for smooth colours:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=day)) + geom_point() + 
    scale_colour_gradient(low="pink", high="red")
```

[image]

Comment: @Andrie Okay thanks. And here's a related question. Should I move straight to ggplot then rather than learning R's native charting?

Comment: @thomas, that's down to personal choice.  My choice was to learn ggplot straightaway, because I liked its consistency of grammar.  But it has its own learning curve.

Comment: Okay I think you've answered the question about native v ggplot with your examples. Great stuff.

Comment: I'd suggest learning base R graphics first. Your graphs won't be as pretty as ggplots at first but it is very flexible and allows you to do pretty much anything you want. The learning curve is also easier. ggplot is always a good idea to learn too though.

Comment: The other benefit to learning ggplot is that you learn one syntax for all types of plots (scatter, bar, lines, etc). Base graphics use a variety of function names (plot, hist, barchart, others??) and all come with their own quirks and expectations. ggplot2 on the other hand will always start with `ggplot()` or `qplot()` and the input data (more or less) will always be in the same format every time. The way ggplot deals with legends and scaling is also uber convenient. Finally, the ggplot website is very handy though I do recommend picking up the book for deeper understanding. </end soapbox>

Comment: @Chase, by "the book" to you mean ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis by Hadley Wickham?

Comment: @Thomas - That's the one. The [website](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) covers much of the same material, but I've appreciated having the book at my desk as an easy reference too.

Comment: I really should buy that book too:)

Comment: @Sacha and Andrie. May I ask whether the rectangular aspect ratio that you have in your examples above and below are choices, or if that's simply a default. Only because I usually use a square aspect ratio, but I thought you might specifically be going rectangular for visualization reasons?

Comment: I prefer rectangular, and there are some strong views that the golden ratio is a very good design choice.  This crops up in nature, mathematics, architecture, art, design, etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio for more information.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the lower level plotting function `points()` to add points to an already existing plot. It works in exactly the same way you create a scatter plot through `plot()` except that it adds points to the currently used plot.

For example:

```
plot(1:10)
points(10:1,col="red")
```

## Edit:

One way to do the colors is by using `rgb()` as Chi suggested. I like to create a dummy variable with values between 0 and 1 and use that as a scalar on the colors. For example:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 0.5*x + rnorm(100)
z <- 0.5*y + rnorm(100)

dum <- (z - min(z)) / (max(z) - min(z))

plot(x,y,col=rgb(1-dum*0.4,1-dum*0.8,1-dum*0.8),pch=16)
```

This makes the points redder as they have a higher value of `z`. Of course you can change `min(z)` and `max(z)` into the bounds of the scale you are interested in.

[image]

Comment: Excellent thank you. That works beautifully. Any idea how I'd vary the colours continuously from point to point?

Comment: @Thomas Look at [RColorBrewer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/index.html) for general color theme (esp. sequential palette) and the `rgb()` and `col2rgb()` base functions to vary the color, e.g. according to value on the x-axis. Alpha blending is also available, e.g. `plot(replicate(2, rnorm(1000)), pch=19, col="#FF737350")`.