# Plotting multiple curves same graph and same scale

Tags: r, plot

This is a follow-up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479822/plotting-4-curves-in-a-single-plot-with-3-y-axes-in-r).

I wanted to plot multiple curves on the same graph but so that my new curves respect the same y-axis scale generated by the first curve.

Notice the following example:

```
y1 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500)
y2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# first plot
plot(x, y1)

# second plot
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x, y2, axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

That actually plots both sets of values on the same coordinates of the graph (because I'm hiding the new y-axis that would be created with the second plot).

My question then is how to maintain the same y-axis scale when plotting the second graph.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. A graphic of what you want would help...

Comment: Just to add to Manoel's comment, the second set of y values are outside the range of the first. Where do you expect them to be plotted?

Comment: @Manoel: that's what I'm looking for actually...

Comment: @joran: yes, sorry, but even changing it to `y2 <- c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105)` it won't work...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

(The typical method would be to use `plot` just once to set up the limits, possibly to include the range of all series combined, and then to use `points` and `lines` to add the separate series.) To use `plot` multiple times with `par(new=TRUE)`  you need to make sure that your first plot has a proper `ylim` to accept the all series (and in another situation, you may need to also use the same strategy for xlim):

```
# first plot
plot(x, y1, ylim=range(c(y1,y2)))

# second plot  EDIT: needs to have same ylim
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x, y2, ylim=range(c(y1,y2)), axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

[image]

This next code will do the task more compactly, by default you get numbers as points but the second one gives you typical R-type-"points":

```
  matplot(x, cbind(y1,y2))
  matplot(x, cbind(y1,y2), pch=1)
```

Comment: Aren't the second set of y values supposed to be 1:5?

Comment: Yeah, this is not working. You can see that these points are not represented in the same y-axis scale, otherwise 2 would be greater than 100... :)

Comment: Now I get the idea. I plot every point at the same time and later I draw the lines. That's nice. Thanks!

Comment: And there is also matplot. I will add a note.

Answer (score 7):

`points` or `lines` comes handy if

- `y2` is generated later, or
- the new data does not have the same `x` but still should go into the same coordinate system.

As your `y`s share the same `x`, you can also use `matplot`:

```
matplot (x, cbind (y1, y2), pch = 19)
```

[image: matplot (x, cbind (y1, y2), pch = 19)]

(without the `pch` `matplopt` will plot the column numbers of the `y` matrix instead of dots).

Comment: how can I annotate the black dots and the red dots with y1 and y2, respectively?

Comment: @dacongy: `pch` accepts one-character symbols (like "A" and "B" or "1" and "2") for each of the columns of the y matrix. If you really need longer text, AFAIK you need to use `text` for each of the columns (or write a mattext function  ;–) )

Answer (score 5):

You aren't being very clear about what you want here, since I think @DWin's is technically correct, given your example code. I think what you *really* want is this:

```
y1 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500)
y2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# first plot
plot(x, y1,ylim = range(c(y1,y2)))

# Add points
points(x, y2)
```

DWin's solution was operating under the implicit assumption (based on your example code) that you wanted to plot the second set of points *overlayed* on the original scale. That's why his image looks like the points are plotted at 1, 101, etc. Calling `plot` a second time isn't what you want, you want to *add* to the plot using `points`. So the above code on my machine produces this:

[image]

But DWin's main point about using `ylim` is correct.

Comment: Points to you. Fixed my y-problem by using same ylim on both. Probably should have used points in retrospect.

Comment: You don't need `c` in range. `range(y1,y2)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is to use `ggplot2`. It takes care of these types of things automatically. The biggest thing is to arrange the data appropriately.

```
y1 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500)
y2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
df <- data.frame(x=rep(x,2), y=c(y1, y2), class=c(rep("y1", 5), rep("y2", 5)))
```

Then use `ggplot2` to plot it

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=class)) + geom_point()
```

This is saying plot the data in `df`, and separate the points by `class`.

The plot generated is[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want, but i'll use lattice.

```
x = rep(x,2)
y = c(y1,y2)
fac.data = as.factor(rep(1:2,each=5))
df = data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=fac.data)
# this create a data frame where I have a factor variable, z, that tells me which data I have (y1 or y2)
```

Then, just plot

```
xyplot(y ~x|z, df)
# or maybe
xyplot(x ~y|z, df)
```

Comment: Or `xyplot(y~x, groups=z, df)`. And without creating new `data.frame`: `xyplot(y1+y2~x)`.

Comment: I know of it, but I never used it! Maybe i should give it a try. +1 for the pointer.