# F# R type provider and cbind

Tags: r, f#, type-providers

I'd like to visualize data with [matplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853204/plotting-multiple-curves-same-graph-and-same-scale) but initially I need to combine them through `R.cbind`.

I have two quantiles arrays `quantiles1` and `quantiles2` like this

```
val it : double [] =
  [|9.493529797e-05; 0.00356456441; 0.006148920477; 0.01201379844;
    0.04056193231; 0.1144207457; 0.3402441047; 0.7572200933; 1.432890804;
    2.755986279|]
```

When I call

```
R.cbind(quantiles1, quantiles2)
```

the result is

```
val it : SymbolicExpression =
                 ...
 [1,] 0.0000949353
 [2,] 0.0035645644
 [3,] 0.0061489205
 [4,] 0.0120137984
 [5,] 0.0405619323
 [6,] 0.1144207457
 [7,] 0.3402441047
 [8,] 0.7572200933
 [9,] 1.4328908043
[10,] 2.7559862789
```

But I'd expect two columns here. 
What is the way how I should use get correct result with`cbind` in F# type provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
let x12 = R.cbind(namedParams ["x1", box x1; "x2", box x2])
R.dim(x12)
// val it : SymbolicExpression = [1] 10  2
```

The reason is that R.cbind expects the following type:
[image]

**Edit**
You can make a helper function if it gets too tedious....

```
let makeRParams (xs:#seq<_>) =
    xs
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> ("x"+i.ToString(),box x))
    |> dict
```

Comment: great, thank you for answer ... I tried something similar but I didn't know that these variables can be named like this in namedParams

Comment: @JozefCechovsky I also wonder if there is some sort of better way, but usually I end up passing data frames anyway, which already have names assigned. I added a helper function that will give the variables a name and box them as well. That way you can skip the `namedParams` nonsense and R will accept a dictionary.