# Multiple axis/scales on a XY-plot in R

Tags: r

How can I plot a second line in a XY-plot, using plot(), to a different scale like this example (purple line)?

[image]

My R code for the first (red) line is something like:

```
p <- sqlQuery(ch,"SELECT wl,param1 FROM qryPlot ORDER BY wl")
plot(p$wl,p$param1,axes=T,xlim=c(400,800),ylim=c(0,100),type="l",col="red")
```

Comment: I think this has been addressed before too. Let me try to find the other Q/As...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479822/plotting-4-curves-in-a-single-plot-with-3-y-axes-in-r
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142944/how-can-i-plot-with-2-different-y-axes-in-r

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-create-a-plot-with-two-y_002daxes_003f  (googling "r faq two y axes" is also useful)

Comment: The R-FAQ is distributed with R. On my device it is part of the help functionality, but it will also be the first hit on a google search for R FAQ .... the google people like R.

Comment: @DWin Sure, but I meant where in the R FAQ? But Ben Bolker already already answered. Thank you both

Comment: It's not *that* hard to search the FAQ for "two y-axes", is it ... ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479822/ = about another situation: 4 different plots in 1 graph. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142944 is ok but not accomplished with plot() function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the general idea:

```
plot(1:10)
par(new=T)
plot(1:10, rep(50, 10), type='l', axes=F, xlab=NA, ylab=NA)
axis(4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I slightly extended the answer by @johncolby to this:

```
x<-1:20
y1<-sqrt(x)
y2<-sqrt(x)*x
plot(x,y1,ylim=c(0,25),col="blue")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x,y2,ylim=c(0,100),col="red",axes=FALSE)
axis(4)
```

(`axes=FALSE` in second plot() command = to prevent labels second axis printed on the left side)

With this result:

[image]

Little problem to solve: labels both y-axes are printed to the left side.