# How to draw multiple Lines from csv in R

Tags: r

I just started using R and like to know how to plot a line . 
With one of my tool  I am doing regression  which  generating csv files. FOrmat is as follows:

```
X ,Y, Y1,Y2
```

From this csv file I like to draw three lines as `(x,y)` , `(x,y1)` and `(x,y2)`. How do I do it from csv file?
Sorry its basic question but appreciates if anyone help me.

Comment: in re-reading your question, it's not clear if you are hung up on the plotting of the data, reading the data into R, or both. The two answers below focus on plotting the data. For background in reading data into R, there's an entire manual dedicated to such things. The relevant portion of that manual is [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html#Variations-on-read_002etable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yourData <- read.csv("yourCSV.csv")
with(yourData, plot(X, Y, type = "l"))
with(yourData, lines(X, Y1))
with(yourData, lines(X, Y2))
```

Also see `?abline`.

Comment: with the above code, each is erasing the the graph and then drawing the line while i like to see all line at same time.

Comment: @CrazyC Weird, that doesn't happen for me. `plot` starts a new window by default, but `lines` adds to the current plot. You can adjust the scope of the initial plot call by using `xlim` and `ylim` arguments; make sure you get the full range of the data.

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably use `matplot` if you want to use base R:

```
#Fake data
x <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y1 = rnorm(100), y2 = runif(100))
#Plot
matplot(x[,1], x[, -1], type="l", lty = 1)
#Everyone needs a little legend love
legend("topright", legend = colnames(x)[-1], fill=seq_along(colnames(x)[-1]))
```

[image]

Or, I'd use ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
#Melt into long format with first column as the id variable
x.m <- melt(x, id.vars = 1)
#Plot it
ggplot(x.m, aes(x, value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

That answer is remarkably similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479822/plotting-4-curves-in-a-single-plot-with-3-y-axes-in-r/5481187#5481187) and several others that pop up as related on the right when you look at that question.

Comment: thanks a lot for solution. First one is working but getting error with ggplot2. I think my R package have not ggplot2.

Comment: @CrazyC `install.packages(ggplot2)`