# How to plot a multicolumn CSV file?

Tags: r, csv, charts

I am very new to R, so excuse me for a question probably stupid.

I've got a multicolumn CSV (plain comma-separated, no quotes) file where the first row is the header, the first column is a contiguous integer index and the other 17 columns are floating-point values of the functions.

The task is to plot all the 17 lines on the same chart (with the same axes).

Sounds very simple but isn't actually very obvious to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `read.csv` to input the data as a data.frame.  Then you have plenty of choices for plotting.  I prefer `lattice` for most investigative work.

Two in lattice.  Here I am creating random data to chart.

```
library(lattice)
d <- data.frame(index=1:20, x=rnorm(20), y=rnorm(20))

> head(d, n=3)
  index         x          y
1     1 -1.065591  0.2422635
2     2 -1.563782 -1.4250984
3     3  1.156537  0.3659411

xyplot(x+y~index, data=d, type='l', auto.key=list(space='right'))
```

You can generate the formula from the names of the columns.  I don't usually do this from the prompt, but use such constructs in code:

```
f <- paste(paste(names(d[,-1,drop=FALSE]), collapse="+"),
           names(d[,1,drop=FALSE]),
           sep=" ~ ")

xyplot(as.formula(f), data=d, type='l', auto.key=list(space='right'))
```

As in Ben's answer, `type='l'` specifies lines. The default is `type='p'` for points.  I added the `auto.key` parameter here, to label the series.

[image]

Comment: After I load my data with `d <- read.table("mytable.csv")` and issue `head(d, n=3)` command, the header line is displayed wit a huge offset - looks empty and is to be scrolled right to see the actual header. When I issue the `xyplot(x+y~index, data=d,type='l')` command, it gives `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found`. But Ben's solution works ok with the same file and your example with random data works too.

Comment: In my example, `x` and `y` are the names of the columns in the data frame.  You would need to use the actual column names.   I should have specified `read.csv` as it will provide the correct defaults (header=TRUE, sep=",") for you.  I will edit to reflect this.   What column names do you have in your data?

Answer (score 26):

Probably the most compact, base-R-only solution is

```
mydata <- read.csv("mydatafile.csv")
matplot(mydata[, 1], mydata[, -1], type="l")
```

- `header=TRUE` is a default option to `read.csv()`, so you don't need to specify the existence of the header row explicitly
- `mydata[, 1]` selects the first column; `mydata[, -1]` selects *all but* the first column
- `type="l"` selects lines (the default is points); see `?matplot`, `?plot` for details of changing line types, colours, etc etc etc ...

Once you know that `matplot` is useful you can search StackOverflow for other examples, e.g. [How to draw multiple Lines from csv in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955493/how-to-draw-multiple-lines-from-csv-in-r)

Comment: Thank you, @ben-bolker, your answer is great at solves my problem. I hope you don't mind me to accept Matthew's answer though as it solves the problem too an Matthew has got much less reputation points yet.