# Plot two columns in R from csv file

Tags: r

I have just started to learn R and I have a problem with plotting some values read from a CSV file.

I have managed to load the csv file:

```
timeseries <- read.csv(file="R/scripts/timeseries.csv",head=FALSE,sep=",")
```

When checking the content of timeseries, I get the correct results (so far, so good):

```
1     2016-12-29T19:00:00Z  6
...
17497 2016-12-30T00:00:00Z  3
```

Now, I am trying to plot the values - the date should be on the x-axis and the values on the y-axis.

I found some SO questions about this topic: [How to plot a multicolumn CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991905/how-to-plot-a-multicolumn-csv-file). But I am unable to make it work following the instructions.

I tried:

```
matplot(timeseries[, 1], timeseries[, -1], type="1")
```

Also, I tried various `barplot` and `matplot` modifications but I usuassly get some exception like this one: `Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values`

Could someone suggest how to tackle this problem? Sorry for elementary question...

Comment: Recommendation: 1) turn your date column into an R date object, 2) turn your value column into a time serie object, 3) plot the final object. You can find how to achieve every step searching on this site. Keywords: `xts`, `POSIXlt`, `strptime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your dates have class Date.

```
dates <- c("2016-12-29T19:00:00Z", "2016-12-30T00:00:00Z")
values <- c(6,3)
df <- data.frame(dates, values)
df$dates <- as.Date(df$dates)
```

Then you could use ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(df$dates, df$values) + geom_line()
```

or even the default

```
plot(df$dates, df$values, type = "l")
```

or with lattice as in the question you referred to

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(df$values ~ df$dates, type = "l")
```

Comment: Oh, I spent so much time looking for the date conversion. This works like a charm. Thanks