# R: how to make multiple plots from one CSV, grouping by a column

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to put multiple plots onto a single visual output in R, based on data that I have in a CSV that looks something like this:

```
user,size,time
fred,123,0.915022
fred,321,0.938769
fred,1285,1.185608
wilma,5146,2.196687
fred,7506,1.181990
barney,5146,1.860287
wilma,1172,1.158015
barney,5146,1.219313
wilma,13185,1.455904
wilma,8754,1.381372
wilma,878,1.216908
barney,2974,1.223852
```

I can read this just fine, using, e.g.:

```
data = read.csv('data.csv')
```

For the moment, a fairly simple plot is fine, so I'm just trying `plot()`, without much to it (setting `type='o'` to get lines and points), and' from solving a past problem, I know that I can do, e.g., the following, to get data for just fred:

```
plot(data$time[which(data$user == 'fred')], data$size[which(data$user == 'fred')], type='o')
```

What I'd like, though, is to have the data for each user all showing up on one set of axes, with color coding (and a legend to match users to colors) to identify different user data.

And if another user shows up, I'd like another line to show up, with another color (perhaps recycling if I have too many users at once).

However, just this doesn't do it:

```
plot(data$size, data$time, type='o',col=c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

Because it doesn't seem to group by the user.

And just this:

```
plot(data, type='o')
```

gives me an error:

```
Error in plot.default(...) : 
  formal argument "type" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

This:

```
plot(data)
```

does do something, but not what I want.

I've poked around, but I'm new enough to R that I'm not quite sure how best to search for this, nor where to look for examples that would hit a use-case like this.

I even got somewhat closer with this:

```
plot(data$size[which(data$user == 'wilma')], data$time[which(data$user == 'wilma')], type='o', col=c('red'))
lines(data$size[which(data$user == 'fred')], data$time[which(data$user == 'fred')], type='o', col=c('green'))
lines(data$size[which(data$user == 'barney')], data$time[which(data$user == 'barney')], type='o', col=c('blue'))
```

This gives me a plot (which I'd post inline, but as a new user, I'm not allowed to yet):

[not-quite-right plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEmwx.png)

which is kind of close to what I want, except that it:

- doesn't have a legend
- has ugly axis labels, instead of just time and size
- is scaled to the first plot, and thus is missing data from some of the others
- isn't sorted by x-axis, which I could do externally, though I'm guessing I could do it fairly easily in R.

So, the question, ultimately, is this:

What's an easy way to plot data like this which:

- has multiple lines based on the labels in the first column of the CSV
- uses the same set of axes for the data in columns 2 and 3, regardless of the label
- has a legend and color-coding for which label is being used for a particular line (or set of points)
- will adapt to adding new labels to the data file, hopefully without change to the R code.

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers on this.

P.S.  I looked around for similar questions, and found [one that's sort of close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955493/how-to-draw-multiple-lines-from-csv-in-r), but it's not quite the same, and I failed to figure out how to adapt it to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. This is doable in base plot, but it's even easier and more intuitive using ggplot2. Below is an example of how to do this with random data in ggplot2

First download and install the package

```
install.packages("ggplot2",repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
require(ggplot2)
```

Next generate the data

```
a <- c(rep('a',3),rep('b',3),rep('c',3))
b <- rnorm(9,50,30)
c <- rep(seq(1,3),3)
dat <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Finally, make the plot

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=c, y=b , group=a, colour=a)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Basically, you are telling ggplot that your x axis corresponds to the c column (dat$c), your y axis corresponds to the b column (y$b) and to group (draw separate lines) by the a column (dat$a). Colour specifies that you want to group colour by the a column as well.

The resulting graph looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Or, using OP's dataset: `ggplot(data,aes(x=size,y=time, color=user))+geom_point()+geom_line()`

Comment: Thanks!  @jlhoward's comment plus the install/require information for ggplot2 has given me what I need!  Much appreciated!  I'll up-vote if/when I can (though somehow my "good question" got down-voted?  Any downvoters care to say what was poor about my question, so I can ask better later?)