# how to plot cluster of time-series in loop with different colors?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, cluster-analysis

I would like to know, how I can plot cluster of time-series with different colors, when I'm using loop. I know that the procedure `ggplot()` do it, but I cannot use it before loop. Here is the code:

```
plot(units_sold[,1], t="l", ylim=c(0,4500))

for (i in 2:126) { 
  if (klaster1[i,2] == "1")
    lines(units_sold[,i])
}
```

Where should I put in the code the option to plot every time-series in cluster with different color?

Comment: Please see [how to make a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: ? I don't see there any help concerning my question

Comment: Check this link for similar problem and solution [Multiple time series in one plot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31455753/3679348)

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(units_sold[,1], t="l", ylim=c(0,4500))

for (i in 2:126) 
 { 
   if (klaster1[i,2] == "1")
   lines(units_sold[,i], col = colors()[i])
  }
```

You can improve colors using some color palette system.